# How can I insert a newline in a framebox?

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, framed

I have several frameboxes in my document, using the following command:

```
\framebox(115,115){ R-Sq: \newline For example}
```

I want to force a new line, but neither `\newline` or `\\` appear to work. Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

TH. has suggested putting the framebox around another box, but specifying the size can be awkward. Here's my (note: plug) solution to the problem:

```
\usepackage{minibox}
...
\minibox[frame]{R-Sq:\\ For example}
```

A ‘minibox’ is exactly equivalent to a tabular in the current implementation; I just wanted the shorter markup.

Comment: Thank you - that also worked. As I have several frameboxes, I am using both answers to be equitable!

Comment: @celenius I forgot to mention you can also centre the contents by writing `\minibox[c]` if that helps.

Comment: Yeah, the length is sort of awkward. As I recall from when I looked a few hours ago, it basically did `\vbox to #1\unitlength{\vss\hbox to #2\unitlength{\hss#4\hss}\vss}`, so that's where I got the width of the `\parbox`.

Comment: `\minibox` even has a `frame` argument, nice.

Comment: @JAB — is that a nudge to update my answer? :)

Answer (score 22):

At the risk of beating a dead horse, I find the framed package works most convenient.

```
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{framed}
   My long text that needs new lines.
\end{framed}
```

You need not worry about sizing--line breaks are automatic. It works well with the beamer class too.

Comment: G'on and beat the horse. This helped me.

Comment: Same here, because I can't use `mdframed` because of a conflict.

Comment: this dead horse creates a conflict, something about \end cannot appear...

Answer (score 7):

If you dig through the chain of macro expansions, you see that `\framebox(x,y)[z]{text}` ends up typesetting `text` in an `\hbox`.

So you can use this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\framebox(115,115){%
    \parbox{115\unitlength}{R-Sq:\\For example}%
}
\end{document}
```

Where all I've done is put the input inside an appropriately sized `\parbox`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and it worked perfectly. (As the text is right against the framebox line, I chose a slightly smaller size (110))

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\framebox{\Longstack[l]{This\\is\\a\\test}}
\framebox{\Longstack[c]{This\\is\\a\\test}}
\framebox{\Longstack[r]{This\\is\\a\\test}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

@celenius One way to insert a newline in a framed box using `\\` (`\newline` itself does not work with this method), using just the `amsmath` package and without defining a `parbox`, is to use `boxed` with `array`. For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\boxed{
\begin{array}{clr}
\textrm{short line}\\
\textrm{long line containing a relatively large number of characters}\\
\textrm{short line again}
\end{array}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put a `minipage` into a `framebox`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
some text 

\noindent
\framebox[\textwidth]  % width of the framebox
{
\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}  % width of the minipage
first line

second line 
\end{minipage}
}

some text 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works fine

```
\framebox{
    \parbox{\columnwidth-4\fboxsep}{sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text sample text }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `-4\fboxsep` and not `-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule`? Also, you have some spurious spaces that add space (and might be the reason for you using `-4\fboxsep` to start with).

Comment: when I use `-4\fboxsep`. It works perfectly, but `-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule` can't. I don't know why but only have the result...

Comment: Are you including [`calc`](//ctan.org/pkg/calc)?

Comment: No.. And only `minted` package can have the results, I just try it, it's amazing...