# Show pageframe for LNCS article class

Tags: margins, framed, lncs

I'm trying to see the "text boundaries" of an [LNCS](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0) document to check whether my floats fit, as the package [pageframe](http://iaus249.nju.edu.cn/Proceedings/pagefram.sty) offers to do. I can't get it to work, unfortunately.

- `\documentstyle[pageframe]{book}` wouldn't fit here, afaik since `\documentclass{llncs}` is how I should declare the document.
- `\documentclass[pageframe]{llncs}` seems to ignore it.
- `\usepackage{pageframe}` complains about `\paperheight` but I don't seem to be able to set that length.

Has anybody managed to use this package or to otherwise have the text box of a LNCS document displayed ?

Comment: `pageframe` seems to be deprecated (it is written for LaTeX 2.09). Don't you get an overfull hbox if your float extends into the margin? Note that you can use the `draft` option to visualize these.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [showframe](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/showframe) package can help with this:

`\usepackage{showframe}`

Comment: @Brent: In my opinion this shouldn't be an answer but a comment to the question. In general, posting questions in an answer is somewhat dubious I think.

Comment: @Hendrik: Just criticism. I've transmogrified it into a brief answer

Comment: @Brent: Thanks. I'm not sure what you mean by "just criticism"; I certainly didn't mean to offend you `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik: That was just as in "justice/gerechte", not just as in "only/nur". No offense ever taken...

Comment: @Brent: Ah, OK, thanks for enlightening me. I seem to be a bit slow on the uptake today. (I actually do know that this "just" is what the name "Justus" is based on.)

Comment: did the trick and works flawlessly on LNCS class. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use [PGF/TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) to draw a rectangle around the text area (or the whole page etc.).

I modified my answer to 
[Stretching a framebox over the whole page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12125/stretching-a-framebox-over-the-whole-page/12128#12128) so it draws the rectangle around the full text area.

In my test it works well with the `llncs` class and others. You can place it in the footer then it is inserted on any page. Note that the rectangle goes to the baseline of the last line, i.e. the lower parts of the text go below it. That's normal and shouldn't be a problem in your case.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\rfoot{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    % Helper nodes
    \path (current page.north west) ++(\hoffset, -\voffset)
        node[anchor=north west, shape=rectangle, inner sep=0, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum height=\paperheight]
        (pagearea) {};
%
    \path (pagearea.north west) ++(1in+\currentsidemargin,-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep)
        node[anchor=north west, shape=rectangle, inner sep=0, minimum width=\textwidth, minimum height=\textheight]
        (textarea) {};
%
    % Framebox
    \draw (textarea.north west) rectangle (textarea.south east);
    %
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\currentsidemargin}{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
    \oddsidemargin%
  \else%
    \evensidemargin%
  \fi%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-100]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: hmm, that sounds a bit overkill, but I'll try it if I don't find anything else doing the trick.