# Print page margins of a document

Tags: margins, framed

Sometimes when I'm reviewing my document and rearranging images and tables, It would be sometimes great to see the page margins.

Is there any easy way to print the page margins when reviewing a document?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show pageframe for LNCS article class](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14087/2975). The answers there also work with other classes.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can achieve this by activating the `showframe` option of the `geometry` package. If you don’t want the package to modify your page layout, you additionally need to pass the `pass` option:

```
\usepackage[showframe, pass]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also achieve this by adding the `showframe` package to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{showframe}
```

Comment: I am trying to show both, the left and the right margin frames for a `memoir` based document. Only the right margin frame is drawn. Why so? see demo code in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/272453/8272