# What is the difference between \usepackage{showframe} and \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}?

Tags: margins, geometry

Some times I see the use of `\usepackage{showframe}`, but other times I see the use of `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`. What is the difference between using one or the other? i.e., When I should use `\usepackage{showframe}` instead of `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}`?

Comment: the package is a different package. See here https://ctan.org/pkg/showframe.

Comment: `showframe` just shows the frame, whereas `geometry`'s main usage is to customize the page layout. Compare the results of `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{showframe}\begin{document}test\end{document}` with `\documentclass{article}\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}\begin{document}test\end{document}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you run

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\the\textwidth; \the\textheight
\end{document}
```

framelines around the text-, header-, and footer-blocks will be drawn, and the text output will be

> 345.0pt; 550.0pt

That's roughly 4.77" and 7.61", or 12.1cm and 19.3cm. The same dimensions would obtain if the `showframe` package weren't loaded at all.

If, on the other hand, you run

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\the\textwidth; \the\textheight
\end{document}
```

you'll still get the framelines, but the textblock parameters are given by

> 430.00462pt; 556.47656pt

That's roughly 5.95" and 7.70", or 15.1cm and 19.6cm.

There may also be differences in terms of the heights and widths of the header, footer, and margin blocks, but I haven't checked.

Comment: I just find out the question [Print page margins of a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14508), it seems that calling the package `geometry` as `\usepackage[showframe, pass]{geometry}` does not change the page margins. But from the question [How to do the memoir headings fix but not have my text going over the page bottom margins?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387257) when using the class `memoir` we need to use the `geometry` package instead of `showframes`, as the `showframes` package is know to not word correctly with the `memoir` package.

Answer (score 8):

if you like to see page layout determined by package `geometry` than you can see it with adding option `showframe` to package.

In case, when page layout is determined by `\documentclass{...}` or some other way and you are curious how page layout looks, then you can see it with adding package `showframe`, which not interfere in layout design. with this package you can also change border thick and color, for example:

```
%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
```