# how to expand a frame to the rest of the page

Tags: framed

I have some introduction text and a figure at the end of the first page.
Now I want to place a framed notes box between those parts, that may go over to the next page.
But I want the frame to fill the whole remaining of the page

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\parbox{7cm}{%
Eingangsdatum:\hfill 19.03.2018\\
Bearbeiter:\hfill\textbf{PMI}
}}

\begin{figure}[b]
\fbox{\parbox{9cm}{%
Ergebnis
}}
\end{figure}        

\begin{framed}
\textbf{Anmerkungen:}\\
%% what to do to expand the frame to the top of the figure-box?
%% or, if the notes are longer than one page, expand to the 
%% bottom of the page
\end{framed}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Stretching a framebox over the whole page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12125/117534)?

Comment: not exactly. My text behind "Anmerkungen:" is processed thru latex, and may result in Text more than a page. So I have a box in the middle of page one (between "Eingangsdatum" and "Ergebnis"), and one box on the next page frameing the hole printable region.

Comment: You mean like [this](https://imgur.com/a/5hKfG), no?

Comment: not exactly: the box on the last page should stretch to the bottom, leaving place for notes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{stretchbox}[1][]{
    sharp corners,
    breakable,
    height fixed for=all,
    height fill,
    colback=white,
    #1}


\begin{document}
\fbox{\parbox{7cm}{%
Eingangsdatum:\hfill 19.03.2018\\
Bearbeiter:\hfill\textbf{PMI}
}}

\begin{figure}[b]
\fbox{\parbox{9cm}{%
Ergebnis
}}
\end{figure}

\begin{stretchbox}
\textbf{Anmerkungen:}
\lipsum[20-25]
\end{stretchbox}    

\end{document}
```

**Breaking across pages**

[image]

**Single page**

[image]

Comment: `height fixed for=all` that was the part I have not seen even with reading three times over the `height fill`documentation. Thanks a lot.