# How to put label on top of an inference rule (bussproofs package)?

Tags: rules, labels

I use bussproofs (instead of [mathpartir](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/)) to layout inference rules.
bussproofs can place labels to the left and to the right of a rule, but not on top of a rule (like mathpartir can do).
Is there an easy way to place the label on top of a rule in bussproofs?

For example, the following will layout a rule with its label on the left.

```
\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{$a$}
  \LeftLabel{Name-of-Rule}
  \UnaryInfC{$b$}
\end{prooftree}
```

I am looking for a bussproofs version of the following mathpartir-based latex code:

```
\inferrule[Name-of-Rule]{a}{b}
```

Here is an example document using mathpartir which produces the desired result (label is on top and left aligned with the rule):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpartir}
\begin{document}

\begin{mathpar}
  \inferrule[Foo]{A \quad B}{C}
\end{mathpar}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of mathpartir]

Here is an example using bussproofs, I do not know how to get the label on top of the rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{A}
  \AxiomC{B}
  \LeftLabel{Foo}
  \BinaryInfC{C}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result with bussproofs]

Comment: You question would be much more understandable if you made two small compilable documents one with `bussproofs` and one with `mathpartir` so that people could play with them. Also, `mathpartir` doesn't appear to be part of TeX Live. Is there a link to it?'

Comment: @AlanMunn Thanks for the useful comments. I added a link to `mathpartir` and example documents.

Comment: You can use a regular `array` to reconstruct the proofs in any way you like. The interface might be different, of course. Would that be an option?

Comment: @Werner Thanks for your suggestion. If I understand you correctly, you are suggesting using arrays instead of bussproofs? I have already typed up my proofs using bussproofs and would rather not change that latex code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After playing around some more, I came up with the following solution.
It uses [savebox as described here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2945), [minibox as described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8680/how-can-i-insert-a-newline-in-a-framebox), and
NewDocumentEnvironment to get the parameter in the end block [as described here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20576/passing-newenvironment-parameters-to-the-end-block).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{minibox}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newsavebox{\topprooftreebox}
\newlength{\topprooftreewidth}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{topprooftree}{m}%
  {\begin{lrbox}{\topprooftreebox}\ignorespaces}%
  {\DisplayProof\end{lrbox}\begin{center}\settowidth{\topprooftreewidth}%
    {\topprooftreebox}\makebox[\topprooftreewidth]{%
    \minibox{{#1}\\\usebox{\topprooftreebox}}}\end{center}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{topprooftree}{\textsc{Foo}}
  \AxiomC{A}
  \AxiomC{B}
  \AxiomC{C}
  \TrinaryInfC{B}
\end{topprooftree}
\begin{topprooftree}{\textsc{Foo}}
  \AxiomC{A}
  \AxiomC{B}
  \AxiomC{C}
  \TrinaryInfC{B}
\end{topprooftree}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It turned out that using lrbox is essential: `\makebox` and  `\bgroup` do not work with package `xcolor`: [see post here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=11374)